# How to generate unique alphanumeric within 8 - 10 length in java

Tags: java

Hi may i know how can i write a code to generate the alphanumeric code which is look like this `HW6KNMQA`, `CMKQ83JX` ? I dont wish to use UUID method. Is there any simple method to generate for this ? ANy help would be appreciated.

What i have done so far;

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;

public String testing() throws Exception
{
    int ID_LENGTH = 10;
    String a = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(ID_LENGTH);

  return a;
}
```

but i received error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils
```

Comment: "I dont wish to use UUID method" any special reason for that?

Comment: because UUID length is too long. i need the code within 8 to 10 length.

Comment: How unique does it need to be?

Comment: You can use the Date to get a unique subset, how unique do you need the  value? I,E multithreadded application with many simultaneous transactions?

Comment: I need to insert 10k data at the same time inside a loop .. so i tried to find for the solution how to get the unique data by using random function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`RandomStringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) from the Apache project. That being said, you do not seem to require a fixed length value, this, I think, could cause trouble down the line since it might make it harder to identify the value you are after.

If this is not a problem, you could use the `Random` function to randomly decide the length of the string to generate.

Comment: @user3835327: `RandomStringUtils` is not part of the default Java SDK. You will need to download the appropriate JAR file to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigInteger.toString(int radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29).

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String n = BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(random.nextLong())).toString(32).toUpperCase();
        if (n.length() > 8) {
            if (n.length() > 10) {
                n = n.substring(n.length() - 10);
            }
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that because this is in base `32` you will not see `WXYZ` but you should see all other characters and digits with equal probability.

Comment: Hi @OldCurmudgeon , may i know this that the every generated code is unique? i need to store up to 10k data, im worried it will duplicated.

Comment: Btw.. appreciated for your answer.

Comment: @user3835327 - No - these will not be unique - they are generated from `Random`. If you need unique, store them in a `Set` or a database and check each one.